# Some basics of compartment search

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I am new to FHIR, and am unable to understand the concept of compartment search.I have read compartment is a group of similar resources, but when we do compartment search we provide the following path: 
`/[compartment]/[id]/?[parameters]`
'/[compartment]/[id]/[type]?[parameters]'
'/[compartment]/id/condition '

Can anyone please give reasons why we are using ID as a parameter in each request, and also please give one one example of each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:
/Patient/1/$everything, however that's not really a compartment based search.  It's a resource-instance specific operation that depends on the existence of compartments to function - it says "find me everything in this patient's compartment"

For compartment based search, you'll either have this:
/[compartment]/[id]/[type] (e.g. /Patient/1/Condition) if you want all records of the specified type within the compartment

or this
/[compartment]/[id]/[type]?[parameters] (e.g. /Patient/1/Condition?category=diagnosis) if you want to further filter the records.

id isn't a parameter, it's identify the compartment.  In the example above, you're saying "I want the conditions that belong to patient 1".  There's no difference between the following two queries:
/Patient/1/Condition
/Condition?patient=1

The only reason we support compartments is that some systems like to do logic or security based on URL.  Nesting queries beneath a selected Patient or Practitioner, etc. lets them do that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm having problems understanding compartments. So, should the following return all Observations related to a patient with id 1032702, or do I need something more? : http://fhir.example.com/Patient/1032702/Observation

Comment: That should do it - provided the server at fhir.example.com supports compartments :)